# Conditionally load Sass stylesheets with variable overrides

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

In our app, we have different clinics, and all patient pages are nested under a clinic, which has branding. We have 100+ clinics, so I'd rather not have something like `= stylesheet_link_tag #{@clinic.name}_theme` in my `application.html.haml` file, and have a theme file that's like

```
// clinic_a.css.sass
a
  color: red

// clinic_b.css.sass
a
  color: blue
```

I'd rather use color variables throughout all my Sass files, then define those variables in separate sheets that get called based on the clinic (found by the params, say). So:

```
// application.css.sass
a
  color: $link_color

h1
  color: $neutral_color

// clinic_a.css.sass
$link_color: #faa
$neutral_color: #ccc

// clinic_b.css.sass
$link_color: #96c7c7
$neutral_color: #bababa
```

The issue is, it seems like the variables have to come first in the asset pipeline, so they'd have to be declared before the other files in my `application.css.sass` file. But obviously, that file doesn't have access to params or anything.

How can I decide which variables file to load based on params, which will then get evaluated all over my `application.css.sass` file, and files included in that?

### Edit

Just to be clear, this would have to work with Rails's asset pipeline.

Comment: You can always make it an erb file, although I'm not convinced that's the best approach.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't load different stylesheets, I would use the [`@if`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_6) function inside sass to conditionally assign variables:

```
EXAMPLE
p {
  @if 1 + 1 == 2 { border: 1px solid;  }
  @if 5 < 3      { border: 2px dotted; }
  @if null       { border: 3px double; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding this. How would the stylesheets have access to the database or the params to tell what style they should display? Also, we have dozens of stylesheets that, and this would require conditional logic for 100+ cases for each element.